# If you marry a non puber girl can you kiss her?

Tags: fiqh, nikah

I read that the dad decide when is the right time to send his daughter to the house of his husband( Imam Malik said that here https://www.noelshack.com/2021-02-3-1610552768-battal.png  he will send her when he thinks she can do the intercourse with out harms

ok but during this time they are already officially married?!
so the husband have the right to stay alone with his wife?
to see here with out her hijab?
and even to kiss her?

the only thing is he doesnt have the right to have intercourse with her since her body isnt ready to do it with out harm

Am I right? Or I am missing something

Comment: Kissing is a kind of intimacy, and it is rather among the things that are disliked to be done in public. And as it may create arousal and therefore lead to intercourse the social perception seems rather negative, in case that a father didn't yet allow his daughter to be intimate with her husband.

Comment: thanks for the reply I agree with you but how about in private  and not in front of everyone?

Comment: This is what I'm addressing to in my second sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! do you have any reference of fiqh about this rule you are not the first who explain me this rule ( on this website)